# Thymeleaf content assistant not working with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

The thymeleaf content assist is not working, when I type th: prefix in the HTML files, only a th:block proposal is showing.

```
<th:block
```

I have tried to move up the Thymeleaf Processor Proposals to the top in the STS/elipse settings for HTML files but not work.

The project is Spring Boot + Thymeleaf, Gradle snippet:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools"
}
```

I have added html namespace:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

change the th namespace to another does not work;

well, the only working time is that th just replaces the HTML th posotion...

```
<table>
        <tbody>
            <tr th:
```

Comment: have you found the solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi, Did you find a solution? I'm working with Eclipse 2022

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue I done the following steps.

1. Open .log file under .metadata of the work-space
2. Open the Thymeleaf template (html) after th: press Ctrl+sapce
3. Check the exception in .log file
   In my case it was groovy runtime exception so I un-install and installed groovy plug-in
   Restart eclipse and thymeleaf content assistant stared working.

   [ groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: org.thymeleaf.extras.eclipse.contentassist.autocomplete.proposals.AttributeProcessorCompletionProposal(org.thymeleaf.extras.eclipse.dialect.xml.ElementProcessor, Integer, Integer, Boolean) ]

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaZig.png)

Comment: I had the same error and  fixed the issue by installing Groovy Development Tools from the Eclipse Marketplace.

Comment: Problem not resolved for me, there is any other way please?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same, and tried a lot of things, then I saw below error in .log file inside .metadata/ folder:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository 2 0 2021-09-03 12:04:19.422
!MESSAGE Server returned lastModified <= 0 for https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-eclipse-plugin/update-site/2.1.2/content.jar
```

So I basically downloaded jar from link:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-eclipse-plugin/update-site/2.1.2/content.jar

and installed this plugin in STS via: Help-> Install New Software ->Add -> <enter name and Select downloaded jar(content.jar) after clicking on Archive>

I Installed the plugin using above steps and it worked for me.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NRqk.png)

Also one more point I have observed, that it is not working with jdk16, it is working fine with jdk8.

Answer (score 0):

After appending the following line to the eclipse.ini, adding the Thymeleaf Nature doesn't fail any more and the content assist works:

--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It may get fixed in future releases until you can use thymeleaf extension on vscode editor as an alternative.

Answer (score -1):

Got same problem but it went away after upgrade Spring Tools 4.