# Thymeleaf content assist not working in Eclipse 2023-09 version

Tags: java, html, css, spring, thymeleaf

I installed thymeleaf plugins from eclipse market place.I can use thymeleaf nature in my project.But thymeleaf content assist is'nt showing in html file.I used eclipse version 2023-09 and thymeleaf 3.1.0.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Welcome. Related? [Thymeleaf content assistant not working with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55879751/12846804) [Github Content Assist Doesn't appear to be working](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-eclipse-plugin/issues/25)